# How to create a nested if statement based on time range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to group a series of time ranges in a column into 4 time range buckets (7AM-12PM, 12PM - 4PM, 4PM-8PM, 8PM -12AM) that I'll display in the next column. So, if the time is 730 AM on the left, the right side gets boring 7AM-12PM. If a time range isn't known, you get "Unknown." I am using a nested if/and functions. Can someone tell me why this formula will only show the Unknown value? I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

```
=IF(AND(G2>=TIMEVALUE("07:00:00"),G2<=TIMEVALUE("12:00:00")),"7AM-12PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIMEVALUE("12:30:00"),G2<=TIMEVALUE("04:00:00")),"12PM-4PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIMEVALUE("04:30:00"),G2<=TIMEVALUE("08:00:00")),"4PM-8PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIMEVALUE("08:30:00"),G2<=TIMEVALUE("23:30:00")),"8PM-12AM","Unknown"))))
```

Comment: Few simple correction is required in your Formula,, replace `04:00:00` with `16:00:00` and `04:30:00` with `16:30:00`,, you get correct answer !!

Answer (score 1):

You got something right in the last time interval that you missed in the second and third.  You need to use 24 hour time (which you used for 23:30:00).  But all of the other times after noon were entered as morning times.  So 4 PM should be 16:00, and 8 PM should be 20:00.

```
=IF(AND(G2>=TIMEVALUE("07:00:00"),G2<=TIMEVALUE("12:00:00")),"7AM-12PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIMEVALUE("12:30:00"),G2<=TIMEVALUE("16:00:00")),"12PM-4PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIMEVALUE("16:30:00"),G2<=TIMEVALUE("20:00:00")),"4PM-8PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIMEVALUE("20:30:00"),G2<=TIMEVALUE("23:30:00")),"8PM-12AM","Unknown"))))
```

Sticking with the same construction, you can actually shorten it a little.  TIMEVALUE converts a text representation of time.  TIME will construct a time from the numerical values.  So the formula would be:

```
=IF(AND(G2>=TIME(7,0,0),G2<=TIME(12,0,0)),"7AM-12PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIME(12,30,0),G2<=TIME(16,0,0)),"12PM-4PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIME(16,30,0),G2<=TIME(20,0,0)),"4PM-8PM",IF(AND(G2>=TIME(20,30,0),G2<=TIME(23,30,0)),"8PM-12AM","Unknown"))))
```

Your formula actually didn't give me "unknown", it just gave wrong intervals.  The revised formula above works for me.  If you were getting "unknown" for everything, there's an additional problem, perhaps the times entered not being recognized as time values (how are you entering them?).

BTW, with nested IFs this long, consider using a lookup instead.

Comment: thank you for catching that error. And I'm not sure why I am getting this error but its driving me mad. I think it has something to do with the formatting of the cells. When I make ANY change to the field and hit enter, it works. I checked the cell format and use the same one, but it has no effect.

Comment: @Vincent, what is the cell's format, and what, exactly, are you typing into the cell?  Also, have you tried replicating this in a new workbook (open a clean spreadsheet, copy in just the relevant formulas for testing, and see if you get the same result).

Comment: That column is a formula based off shortened time characters from another field. Its a bit of a mess but I am generating MANY dummy data records so this ends up being most efficient as formulas to plug in/change. I think its something to do with Excel thinking this cell is text, bc I designated it as such. So, to get around it, I created yet another column where I multiply this field by *1 and it works. Phew!

Comment: @Vincent, kudos for figuring that out.  If there's a way to put that into an answer that would apply to others, consider answering your own question and sharing the knowledge.  :-)